# How to convert coefficient of determination to a convex problem

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to set the coefficient of determination as a constraint but I have trouble rewriting the CoD into a convex problem. In my problem y is a fixed variable, can I eliminate it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are  $x_1,...,x_n$ the choice variables in the optimimzation problem and $y_1,...,y_n$ and $r$  are given?

Comment: basically, I use r as a penalty in a loss function (Langrarian approach), x in this function is a predicted variable, y is a fixed variable (it doesn't change in each iteration)